# How do you index all rows in a column and grab specific elements to create a new column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, function, for-loop, indexing

Currently I am working on my own project and I am attempting to create a new column that is based off an if statement condition in which I am trying to return an indexed element from a column. I am having issues indexing all rows and then grabbing the specific index I want.

Overview:

**Dataset name = fivb_2019**

'Result' is an object column and the final score of the volleyball match. I am trying to take an indexed element of this column to create a new column e.g.(set_one_points)

row value examples
**rows 5-7 in the dataframe contain the value below**

```
                       0-2 (10-21, 16-21)
```

I am trying to get the indexed value [5:7] for the home team and [8:10] for the away team

```
for i in fivb_2019['Result']:
print (i[5:7])
```

When I run this for loop I am able to produce all of the results I desire for my column, but when I put this for loop in my function I return only the value 10 for the home team at index [5:7] and value 21 at index [8:10]. Here is the function:

```
def fill_set_one (Result, teamid,home_teamid):
    for i in fivb_2019['Result']:
    
        if home_teamid == teamid:
            return (i[5:7])
        
        else:
            return (i[8:10])

fivb_2019['set_one_points'] = fivb_2019.apply(lambda x: fill_set_one(x['Result'], 
                                             x['teamid'], x['home_teamid']),axis=1)
```

The function runs, but the results from the value_counts of my new column [set_one_points] only return these values:

```
fivb_2019['set_one_points'].value_counts()
```

#### '10'  111319 times

#### '21'  111236 times

I think when I am attempting to index within the function i([5:7]) it might be grabbing only columns five to seven and the string index '10'. Because in the last line of code you can see that in row 223765 and others that 13 should be the returned result.

```
                              1-2 (13-21, 21-14, 11-15)
```

Other row examples

```
                       2-1 (16-21, 21-18, 22-20)
                       2-1 (18-21, 23-21, 16-14)
                       2-0 (21-19, 21-19)
```

Just confused why I can't return all the results within the function to create my new column.

Thanks for the help in advance, I appreciate it.

Kyle

Comment: I'm pretty confused. My guess, which could be completely wrong, is, that you should set ```axis=0```. But, again, it's a wild guess.

Comment: Thanks for trying Timus! But when I run the lambda expression the axis has to equal 1 to recognize the columns